# "Show"ing records with Unicode (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

If we run the following Haskell code:

```
data R = R {μ :: Double} deriving Show

main = print $ show $ R 3
```

We get:

`"R {\956 = 3.0}"`

What is a good way to handle Unicode names for `Show`ing?

Comment: The `'\956'` is just how GHC *shows* `Char`s outside a certain range (and thus `String`s with those `Char`s in them). You'd have to roll your own `show` function for `Char` and `String`. btw, I don't know if you've noticed, but if you remove the `show` from the above program, it will print `R {μ = 3.0}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`print . show` will `show` whatever you're `print`ing twice! The type signature of `print` tells you:

```
 print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

So you can just `print` anything that instantiates `Show` directly. `print . show` is not necessary!

If you `Show` a `Char`, you get the escape code for non-ASCII stuff — this is just a design decision. If you take the 'Show'able data type and first use `show` on it, what you're `print`ing is not the data type itself, but its `String` representation given by the data type's `Show` instance.

Comment: Just a little addition: if you have a string already, you can use `putStr` and `putStrLn` instead of `print`. When I was starting out, I always found this a bit confusing...